# How to output a structure sub-navigation of current page

Tags: structure

I've got a single structure menu for my entire site which consists of a title and a single related entry. I use that to output the main menu, which uses this code:

```
<section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="right">
        {% nav link in craft.entries.section('menu') %}
        <li class="{% if link.slug == craft.request.getSegment(1) %}active{% endif %} {% if link.hasDescendants() %}has-dropdown{% endif %}"> {# Checks if              the page link is the same as the slug of current page #}
            <a href="{{ link.relatedEntry[0].url }}">{{link.title}}</a>
            {% ifchildren %}
            <ul class="dropdown">
                {% children %}
            </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}
        </li>
        {% endnav %}
    </ul>
</section>
```

On the top level pages, in their template they have a sidebar which should output the menu items in that main section - all singles. Is there a way to do this or do I need to create separate Structures for each section?

Comment: Why don't use use the structure for the content also? I don't see the benefits of using a bunch of singles and then have to manage the structure of them in a separate structure section using entries fields.

Comment: with "top level pages" you meant the singles, related to a top level entry from your structure, right?

Comment: Practically every page on the site has a different layout - and as far as I can tell it's not possible to set different templates for entries in a Structure channel

Comment: Yes you can! That's where [entry types](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entry-type-templates) come into the game.

Comment: Entry types let you use different fields, not different templates (as far as I can tell)

Comment: Hey code knight, you didn't click the link I provided!

Comment: Ahh ok I see - managed to miss that in the docs, thanks. Dynamic templates. Now my head is spinning with flexibility again ><

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16589/discussion-between-codeknight-and-carlcs).

Comment: codeknight, you could also use a combine approach like I outlined in this answer: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1474/125

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first have to get the corresponding entry in your "menu" structure and then build your navigation upon that item.

Use the [`relatedTo()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) parameter for that. The `entry` entry model that you automatically get on that single template is the `targetElement` of that relation, but you should be fine using the less specific `element` property used with the short syntax `relatedTo(myEntryModel)`.

```
{# Get the (one!) related entry from the "menu" structure #}
{% set menuItem = craft.entries.section('menu').relatedTo(entry).first() %}

{# Check if there are descendant entries #}
{% if menuItem.hasDescendants() %}

    {# Get entries to build the sub-menu #}
    {% set subMenu = craft.entries.descendantOf(menuItem) %}

    {# Output the sub menu #}
    <ul>
        {% nav link in subMenu %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
                {% ifchildren %}
                    <ul>
                        {% children %}
                    </ul>
                {% endifchildren %}
            </li>
        {% endnav %}
    </ul>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hey carlcs - thank you! That code worked perfectly (after I fixed the variable names). Makes perfect sense when you read the code, it's just knowing the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% set sidebarNav = entry.getChildren() %}

{% if sidebarNav | length %}

        <ul>
            {% for entry in sidebarNav %}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Although I'm not sure what you mean by all singles? Is this what you're after? It will return all children of the current structure page.

Comment: That doesn't output anything. By "All singles" I mean all the pages that need to appear in the navigation are Singles.

Comment: Are these singles related to each relevant structure page? If so could you do a loop through the related field to display them?

{% for entry in entry.relatedFieldName %}
 <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}

Comment: @Mart that wouldn't work because the entries field to do the relations is added to the structure entries.