# Adding active class to globally cached navigation

Tags: cache, navigation

I have a structure which controls my main site navigation.
It's the same across the site so it is best to cache globally as opposed to a cache of the navigation or every url.

The last answer on this pages says that you can use Twig's replace filter to achieve this:
[Would you use a Structure as navigation over multiple sections (channel entries, indexes and singles)?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/would-you-use-a-structure-as-navigation-over-multiple-sections-channel-entries)

My code below shows the active class being placed on the li tag but that doesn't work with the cache globally.

Can it be done with Twig's replace filter?

```
{% cache globally for 3 years %}
  {% set entries = craft.entries.section('navigation') %}

  <ul class="right">
    {% nav entry in entries %}
    <li class="{{ entry.hasDescendants() ? 'has-dropdown' : "" }}{{ craft.request.segment(1) == entry.slug ? ' active' : "" }}">
      {# Check for entry type / get related entry #}
      {% if entry.type == 'customLink' %}
        {# Link to a custom url #}
        <a href="{{ entry.customUrl }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
      {% elseif entry.type == 'relatedEntryLink' %}
        {% set linkedEntry = entry.relatedEntry.limit(1).first() %}
        <a href="{{ linkedEntry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
      {% else %}
        {# Link to a structure entry #}
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
      {% endif %}
      {# Repeat this for child entries #}
      {% ifchildren %}
      <ul class="dropdown">{% children %}</ul>
      {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
    {% endnav %}
  </ul>
{% endcache %}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can!

The first thing you need to do is to add the entire cached content into a single variable:

```
{% set navigation %}
    {% cache globally for 3 years %}
        {# YOUR CACHED CONTENT #}
    {% endcache %}
{% endset %}
```

Then you need to add some dummy placeholder tags on your `<li>` tag and your `<a>` tag which then can be used by `|replace` filter to make the replacement.

For `<li>`

```
<li class="{{ entry.hasDescendants() ? 'has-dropdown' : "" }} data-class-{{entry.slug}}">
```

For `<a>` (You need to modify this for each different entry type)

```
<a href="{{ entry.url}}" data-url="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
```

After all this you'll have special "tags" in your cached content that you can run some replacement on, like this:

```
{{ navigation|replace({('data-url="' ~ craft.request.getUrl() ~ '"'): 'class="active"'})|replace({('data-class-' ~ craft.request.segment(1)): 'active'})|raw }}
```

*You can run two `|replace` filters after each other, you could just split them up into two steps. Also, this code is untested - I just wrote it from my head so please be aware there might be some typos etc..*

Comment: Thanks - great job - only need the active class on the li so just need the 1 filter. Cheers!

Comment: If it solved your issue please approve the answer. Cherrio!