# Caching matrix that contains Freeform field

Tags: cache, plugin-freeform

I've got a matrix block that most pages on my site are built from, and one of its blocks is a Solspace Freeform form field. I want to be able to cache the entire output of the matrix, but that makes Freeform see all form submissions as spam, since their hash gets cached too.

So I tried https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-nocache but couldn't get that to work as the whole matrix (including the form) gets cached outside of the `{% nocache %}` tag. So then I tried:

```
{% set bodyIncludesForm = entry.body.type('form') | length > 0 %}
{% cache globally using key craft.request.path unless bodyIncludesForm %}
...
```

... which seems to work, but that `entry.body.type('form')` call adds 32 queries which kind of defies the point of the caching!

Any idea how to get round this, without turning off Freeform's spam check?

Comment: Not exactly sure what the FreeForm markup is like, but I've done something similar to the solution [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13852/how-can-i-prevent-csrf-tokens-from-being-cached) for csrf tokens.

Comment: Thanks @jsun. Freeform doesn't use csrf tokens – it outputs a hidden field called "formHash" which I guess might work the same way. But the only way to output that myself (to do a find and replace) would be to call `entry.body.type('form')` outside of the cache loop, and that seems really expensive, adding 32 queries.